# MFC .dll debug assertion

Tags: windows, mfc, atl

I am trying to create a shell extension but I'm getting a debug assertion at this line of code:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE HINSTANCE AFXAPI AfxGetResourceHandle()
    { 
        ASSERT(afxCurrentResourceHandle != NULL);  // here
        return afxCurrentResourceHandle; }
```

What's the problem with it?
I have created this class

```
class CMyExtShellExtApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BOOL CMyExtShellExtApp::InitInstance()
{   
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    return CWinApp::InitInstance();
}

int CMyExtShellExtApp::ExitInstance()
{
    return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

Still the error remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put this line:

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

at the very beginning of the function causing the assertion in your code.